# Looking for DOM-independent JavaScript templating system works \w plain text

Tags: javascript, open-source, server-side, template-engine, plaintext

Is there a templating library/system/engine/technique written in javascript that:

- Doesn't screw up plain-text (non-html) templates ( like tabs and line breaks )
- But also works with HTML
- Doesn't have it's own [DSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language) for loops and conditions (uses pure JS)
- Can be run server-side without the DOM

...and is open-source licensed?

Comment: I can probably start by safely saying the resig's tmpl doesnt work for this, since it regexes line breaks out and such... Yet my current path is to try and re-use the good parts of that and make it more generalized. Does this mean I'm re-doing the microsoft thingy or is it worth it? 

In the meantime anyhow, if anyone has thoughts on the above question .dot.dot.dot.

Comment: http://www.yajet.net/ ? Nope, sorry, has funky DSL.

Comment: and then there's PURE... which isn't so PURE http://gist.github.com/660658

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded Javascript?

http://embeddedjs.com/

Comment: So far, so good. I've added "exports.EJS = EJS" to the bottom of ejs.js and can render a nice ANSI colored template in the terminal using nodejs ... sweet!! I have yet to run proper tests with more complex templates but I'm voting this up, since it's obviously a very right answer :)

Comment: To think of it, I've already looked at the other options... mustache, all the lame tmpl() customs lying here and about... A correct answer!

Comment: Thanks! Yes, the simple fact that you can sprinkle data around in your html AND use loops in an ejs means you should be able to do pretty much anything, since you can do complicated processing in your real javascript and pass in the resulting data to your EJS object's .render() function. Hope it's all you need!